# Prokhorov-like convergence

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and for any $A\subseteq X$ define
$$
  A^\delta:=\{y\in X:\exists x\in A \text{ such that }d(x,y)\leq \delta\}.
$$
Under which conditions on $(X,d)$, $A \subseteq X$ and a probability measure $P$ does it hold that
$$
  \lim\limits_{\delta\to 0}P(A^\delta) = P(A).
$$

Comment: For starters, it holds when A is closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\delta_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence decreasing to $0$. Then $A^{\delta_k}\downarrow \overline{A}$ (the closure of $A$ for the topology induced by $d$), hence 
$$\lim_{k\to +\infty}\mathbb P(A^{\delta_k})=\mathbb P(\overline{A}).$$
So the condition we want is $\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(\overline{A})$.